# Swift: how to zoom in/out background pattern image of UITextField/UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I have been asked to set a background pattern image of UITextField/UITextView in the iOS app I am developing. This background image is just a png file simulating a piece of graph paper. Anyway, the result is different according to the object to which it is applied:
-if it's a UITextView the result is quite good;
-on the contrary, if it is a UITextField the background image is too much zoomed in. 
You can see this from the following picture:

[image]

The instruction I use in both cases it

```
cell.info.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icons/quadretti.png")!)
```

How can I correct it?
Thank you

**UPDATE**

I have just read, somewhere in documentation, that background image is completely ignored if the borders of UITextField are round. So I tried to change them and it works. Strange decisions...

Comment: Try to set your `textfiled` background like this `cell.textField.background = UIImage(named: "icons/quadretti.png")`

Comment: I had tried it but I didn't see anything...as if it was nil